# Getting a column value from database and manipulate it with a textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm working with two forms in my project (Form1 & Form2)

On Form1 user is asked to enter Username (textboxUsername) & Password (textboxPassword)

When user is logged in, Form2 pops up as his account where he can see his ID, Username, Name, Surname, Birthday and Money columns.

Login part:

```
MessageBox.Show("Data verified!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                this.Hide();
                Form2 frm2 = new Form2("Welcome: " + textBoxUsername.Text, textBoxUsername.Text);
                frm2.ShowDialog();
```

Now on Form2 button1, user can see his columns:

```
public class Form2: Form
{
    private string currentUserName = string.Empty;
    public Form2(string welcome, string UserName)
    {
       label2.Text = welcome;
       currentUserName = UserName;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constring = @"Data Source=V-K\;Initial Catalog=ATMKlientet;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(" select * from Clients where Username=@uname", conDataBase);
            cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", currentUserName);

    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
        dbdataset = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dbdataset);
        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

        bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
        sda.Update(dbdataset);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Now, in Form2 I want to add a textBox where logged in user can type a numeric value. If his Money column is 100, when he type 50 in textBox, Money column should remain 50 in the database. Else if the column value is ex.100 and user withdraw 200, it should generate error. It's like subtraction or withdraw everytime a user enters a value in the textBox.

Answer (score 0):

Use `textbox_keydownEvent`

```
textBox1.KeyDown += textBox1_KeyDown;
```

Method inside code:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) //it will only allow numeric keys
        {
            e.Handled = true; //it will handle every non-numeric key, and will only allow integers and control keys
        }
        else
               //write your code to what ever you want to do with database or gridview columns
    }
```